# Как сохранять в цикле модели в список?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, model

Как сохранять в цикле модели с разными именами?
Например:

```
list_models = []    
for i in range(30):
    model = LGBMRegressor(**params)
    model.fit(X,y)
    list_models.append(model)
```

Но сохраняем не с одинаковым названием, а с разным, получая в итоге [model0,model1,model2,...,model29]

Comment: добавьте счетчик на итерации и выводите его вместе с названием

Comment: как вариант, вижу создание моделей-пустышек с одинаковым именем: list_models = [LGBMRegressor(**params) for i in range(30)] - у них будут разные индексы и соответственно их можно обучать?

Comment: мне кажется вы пере-изобретаете [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) ;)

Comment: Максим, можно попросить удалить вопрос? По идее мне нужно было другое как оказалось.

Comment: @nick_n_a метку удалил, очевидно - опечатка.